# Python: i cant do substitution

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using python2.7

I ran this code

```
print r.data
print r[0][action-1].data
```

then it throws this.

> [[ 0.34642464  0.39359313 -1.24270797 -0.89923799  0.11451679 -0.49929592]]
>
> -0.499295920134

then, i tried to substitution "r" like this

```
r[0][action-1].data = 1
```

but i couldn't.

```
print r[0][action-1].data
```

> -0.499295920134

what's my problem?
i imported this.

```
import numpy as np　　　　　　　　
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import random
import chainer
from chainer import cuda
from chainer import serializers
import chainer.functions as F
from chainer import optimizers
```

`print(type(r))` is

> class 'chainer.variable.Variable'

```
print (type(r[0])
```

is also

> class 'chainer.variable.Variable'

Comment: The class you are trying to change isn't `r` but `r[0][action-1]`. As so you need to print that class and show it here, i.e. `print(type(r[0]))`. Apparently [chainer](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v2/chainer/variable.py) is in Github so its possible to see the source code online. Curiously enough I don't see any `__getItem__` method to overload the `[]` operator so I don't know what objects you are going through (different version perhaps). I noticed however that `data` is a property with a setter (check `@data.setter`).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I print "type r([0])" so please check it . thank you.